# Swift multiple viewcontroller need to use as a bottom sheet within rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to create Bottom Sheet ViewController. Inside root viewcontroller I have four buttons, each and every button click action present different viewcontrollers. That viewcontrollers should be present like a bottom sheet. How to do this? Please provide some idea without cocoa pods.

[image: Example Bottom Sheet Image]

Comment: have you try to use containerView?

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/gordontucker/FittedSheets

Answer (score 1):

You can check this post please

https://martinnormark.com/presenting-ios-view-controller-as-bottom-half-modal/

[image]

Comment: I already seen this. But we can't change background transparent without animation. I am trying exactly which is I mentioned above screen.

Comment: View this, I could serve you, just touch the size https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am checking without cocoapods

Comment: With pleasure, from there you can download the library and include it manually without the need for cocoapods

Comment: Yes I am trying. Once its success I will update you here. Thank you @Daniel Fernando Muñoz Melendez